# Too many redirections jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Im trying to make data scraper of page panoramafirm.pl but I'm getting "Too many redirections" error is it possible to fix? Here is my code:

```
int pageCount = 1;
try {
    while (true) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://panoramafirm.pl/akcesoria_do_komputerów/firmy," + pageCount+".html").timeout(0).get();
        Elements goToNext = doc.getElementsByClass("icon-right-open-mini");
        if (goToNext.size() > 0) {
            pageCount++;
            System.out.println(pageCount);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    } 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Tried also with connect method `.followRedirects(true)` in jsoup and selenium with phantomJS:

```
int pageCount = 1;
try {
    while (true) {
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\phantomjs.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driver.get("http://panoramafirm.pl/akcesoria_do_komputerów/firmy," + pageCount+".html");
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());

        Elements goToNext = doc.getElementsByClass("icon-right-open-mini");
        if (goToNext.size() > 0) {
            pageCount++;
            System.out.println(pageCount);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } 
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    } 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Im getting also too many redirections when using proxy with jsoup or selenium or on my normal browsers (although some pages like hide.me can show me webpage). Is this some type of ban method. Can i do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

After invoking given web page I can see I got response with code 302 and Location header set to https.

Use https in url.

Comment: Changing url to https doesn't seem to make any difference, although in error log I'm still having an http address: 'java.io.IOException: Too many redirects occurred trying to load URL http://panoramafirm.pl' Do I have to make some specific configuration? (tried adding user agent, referrer and setting .validateTLSCertificates(false))